# how to use service in controller agularjs

Tags: angularjs

My code in link : 
    https://pastebin.com/SZAXb6xE

```
Why when i entered input to 


    <div id="simple" ng-controller="FormController">
            <p>Input your number:</p>
            <input ng-model="Number" ng-change="check_info()" id="Number" value="2" />
        </div>
```

When i entered input,it's not call to function in my service, it don't have error. Why it's not working

Comment: Please provide the relevant code as a [mcve] **in the question body.**  Links to outside websites can change or break, causing people reading the question in the future to have incomplete information.  Not to mention the people trying to use mobile devices....

Comment: looking at your pastebin, you aren't importing your factory as a dependency into your `FormController`, and aren't attaching the function to `$scope` either.  Also, I suspect you might not want to call that function on every `ng-change` event, since that will happen every time a new character is typed in the input.

Comment: that is all my code

Comment: i don't know why ng-change don't call to function in factory service

Comment: yes, but post it ***here***, not pastebin.  and `ng-change` can't call your factory, because it only calls functions on the `$scope` of your controller.  As I said, you haven't imported your factory so your controller can use it, and you haven't attached the function to `$scope`.  do those things, and it should work.

Comment: you right. I change to '.service' and it work